# Parse text/json data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am collecting HTTP response and it comes back in the text/json form. The original format is as follows:

```
{"param" => "value", "interesting_param" => [{"parama1"=>vala1,"parama2"=>vala2,"parama3"=>vala3,"parama4"=>vala4,"parama5"=>vala5},
{"paramb1"=>valb1,"paramb2"=>valb2,"paramb3"=>valb3,"paramb4"=>valb4,"paramb5"=>valb5}]}
```

When I do a JSON.parse(response.body)["interesting_param"], I can retrieve this output:

```
{"parama1"=>vala1,"parama2"=>vala2,"parama3"=>vala3,"parama4"=>vala4,"parama5"=>vala5},
{"paramb1"=>valb1,"paramb2"=>valb2,"paramb3"=>valb3,"paramb4"=>valb4,"paramb5"=>valb5}
```

How can I capture only the following from the full result-set above.

```
`parama1-vala1`, `parama2-vala2` and `parama5-vala5`
`paramb1-valb1`, `paramb2-valb2` and `paramb5-valb5`
```

**Update**
I did try further on this & now I am thinking of making use of loop.
The way I am attempting to do this is:

1. Find the count of records, for example, if:

> test =
>   {"parama1"=>vala1,"parama2"=>vala2,"parama3"=>vala3,"parama4"=>vala4,"parama5"=>vala5},
>   {"paramb1"=>valb1,"paramb2"=>valb2,"paramb3"=>valb3,"paramb4"=>valb4,"paramb5"=>valb5}

Then, `test.count` will be **2**.

Now if somehow I can use a loop to iterate over elements in `test`, then I might be able to capture specific elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exact value? Your syntax is invalid in the sample code. Also the exact output format you want.

Comment: @Dogbert How is syntax invalid here? I've only sanitized the real data. That's all.

Comment: You probably meant to have a `[` before and `]` after the 5 lines of data.. ?

Comment: okay. The original data is { "p" => 'v", ..., "interesting_param" => [{"<interesting-value-the-data-that-I-presented>"}]}. Out of the original data, I took out the interesting param - value pair. And the question corresponds to this specific set of data. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, and what's the exact output you want for the data in the question?

Comment: Please edit your question after reading http://sscce.org. We need more information to help you.

Comment: I have updated the question properly now. Please check.

Comment: Any ideas to parse it...?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to map each hash into a list of strings made by joining the string version of the key with the string version of the value, joined by a '-'.

```
JSON.parse(response.body)["interesting_param"]
```

The above code should give you a ruby list of hashes.

```
interesting_bits = JSON.parse(response.body)["interesting_param"]
result = interesting_bits.map{|bit| bit.map{|k,v| "#{k}-#{v}"}}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

```
puts result.inspect
#prints 
# [ ["parama1-vala1","parama2-vala2","parama3-vala3","parama4-vala4","parama5-vala5"] , ["paramb1-valb1","paramb2-valb2","paramb3-valb3","paramb4-valb4","paramb5-valb5"] ]
```

I don't understand what criteria you are using for then filtering this down to just 1,2 and 5... but that is easily done too. I would do that to the hashes before converting them to string lists.

Comment: Thanks Nigel. I made use of the first part - JSON.parse(response.body)["myvar"]. For some reason now though, I am getting the error: JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '<xml/json response here>'. Any idea why it stopped working..?

Comment: Because your JSON is no longer formatted correctly. Something has changed in the code making the JSON. Your question is really unclear. What is the context for this code? It sounds like you need to brush up on your basic Ruby, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html should help.